# "Preparing to delete" message box -- what's going on behind the scenes?

Tags: document-library, delete

I'm currently attempting to delete a folder located within a [document library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-a-document-library-3b5976dd-65cf-4c9e-bf5a-713c10ca2872) that has 5000 subfolders, and each subfolder contains 2-7 files, totaling just over 6GB.

The problem is, whenever I highlight the root folder and select delete, the following message box appears, and it is taking **forever.....**

[image: preparing to delete msg window]

*Viewing the document library in an explorer window. For the 1.01 GB that has so far been discovered, it's taken roughly 40-45 minutes.*

My question is: why is SPO taking so long to "discover" all the files in the root folder? Why can't it just remove the directory of the root folder, similar to rmdir in cmd. **What exactly is going on when the "preparing to delete" message box appears?**